# SQL Inner Join Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Table - Customers

```
id FirstName LastName 
23 James     Smith       
24 Tom       Raven 
25 Bob       King
```

Table - Orders

```
id CustomerID 
30 23
31 24
32 23
33 25
```

Table - Products

```
OrderID Product1 Product2 Product3
30      1        0        0
31      2        0        0
32      0        1        1
33      2        1        0
```

I want to count the total number of Products for each Customer so answers would be:

```
CustomerID FirstName LastName Total
23         James     Smith    3
24         Tom       Raven    2
25         Bob       King     3
```

So far I've got for the SQL query:

```
SELECT Customers.id, Orders.id,
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.id = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Products ON Orders.id = Products.OrderID
```

Not sure how to count up the products though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a strange database design. You may want to normalize it. A products table should contain products not order details. Order details on the other hand should be lines in an order, i.e. one record per product in the order.

Comment: @onedaywhen A normalised design would allow expansion of products without requiring structural change. E.g.: (order_id,product_id,quantity) - I'm not saying that this is the right structure, but it's indicative of a normalised approach.

Comment: @onedaywhen: You are right; "normalize" is the wrong term. The design doesn't really violate a normal form. So it's more about proper relational design. A product is an entity, same as a user or an order, so it should not be a column in a table, but a row. Once you need to add a user, an order or a product you'd add a row. In the design shown, however,you would have to add a column for a fouth product and accordingly make changes to the queries accessing the products. So this is not about normalization as defined by the normal forms, but still about a well structured relational database.

Comment: @onedaywhen If we agree that a purpose of 1NF is to 'minimize redesign when extending the database structure', then it's 1NF.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I agree there's a smell here e.g. attributes suffixed 1, 2 and 3 are summarized together suggests they should have been together in the first place. However, if we don't know what `Product1` is and how it is different from `Product2 ` etc then we should be really careful about applying scientific terms such as 'normalization'.

Comment: @onedaywhen I prefer to take a Nietzschean view. Life's too short otherwise.

Comment: @Strawberry: ah yes, that bloke who liked to employ scientific terms but couldn't explain what they meant when challenged :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.id as CustomerID
    ,(sum(p.Product1) + sum(p.Product2) + sum(p.Product3)) as ProductCount
from Customers c
inner join Orders o on c.id = o.CustomerID
inner join Products p on o.id = p.OrderID
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
SELECT c.id as CustomerID, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
    sum(p.Product1 + p.Product2 + p.Product3) as total 
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
ON c.id=o.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN Products p
ON o.id=p.OrderID
group by c.id,c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

And as  @Thorsten Kettner's comment, you should consider normalizing your table design.

Comment: ThorstenKettner and Strawberry both claimed it wasn't fully normalized but when challenged neither could actually name a normal form that is being violated. How about you?

Comment: @onedaywhen yes, normalized may not be the word here. IMO I think products should be data, not fixed in column in table Products, and we will have table `orders_product(id, productid, numberOrdered)` . How should the word be here? Redesign table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.id, Customers.firstname, Customers.lastname,count(*) as total FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.id=Orders.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN Products 
ON Orders.id=Products.OrderID
group by Customers.id,Customers.firstname, Customers.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause! Normally it includes the selected columns that are not arguments to a set function.

```
SELECT O.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, count(*) as Total
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN Orders O ON C.id = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Products P ON O.id = P.OrderID
GROUP BY O.CustomerID, C.FirstName, C.LastName
```

PS. Now using table aliases, to save some typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Total
  FROM ( SELECT id AS CustomerID, FirstName, LastName FROM Customers ) AS c
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT id AS OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders ) AS o
       NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT OrderID, SUM( Product1 + Product2 + Product3 ) AS Total
          FROM Products 
         GROUP
            BY OrderID ) AS p;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more conventional approach might be as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;

CREATE TABLE customers
(customer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers VALUES
(23,'James','Smith'),
(24,'Tom','Raven'),
(25,'Bob','King');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

CREATE TABLE orders
(order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,customer_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(30 ,23),
(31 ,24),
(32 ,23),
(33 ,25);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_detail;

CREATE TABLE order_detail
(order_id INT NOT NULL
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,quantity INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(order_id,product_id)
);

INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES
(30  ,1 ,1),
(31  ,1 ,2),
(33  ,1 ,2),
(32  ,2 ,1),
(33  ,2 ,1),
(32  ,3 ,1);

SELECT c.*
     , SUM(od.quantity) total 
  FROM customers c 
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
  JOIN order_detail od 
    ON od.order_id = o.order_id 
 GROUP 
    BY c.customer_id;

+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+
| customer_id | firstname | lastname | total |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+
|          23 | James     | Smith    |     3 |
|          24 | Tom       | Raven    |     2 |
|          25 | Bob       | King     |     3 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+
```